# How to Incremental ID column with UPDATE from specific value in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a table as below

```
ID Name Code
1   x     y
5   c     v
3   v     h
10  k     4
23  m     g
```

Now I would like to re order number from 5000 as below

```
ID Name Code
5001   x     y
5002   c     v
5003   v     h
5004   k     4
5005   m     g
```

what would be the quickest query SQL Server to handle this as the table contains over million rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution

```
declare @a as int;
SET @a = 5000;  
    UPDATE tablename SET @a=id=@a+1;
```

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near '='.

Comment: Thanks I figured it out. the equation order was wrong. it should be @a = id=@a+1

Answer (score 0):

use cursor to update all rows in the table

```
 DECLARE @i int=5000
DECLARE cur cursor FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY
FOR
 SELECT  id
FROM tbl
DECLARE @d varchar(50)
OPEN cur
 FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @d
 WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
 BEGIN 
UPDATE dbo.tbl
SET id=@i+1
WHERE id=@d

FETCH NEXT FROM cur  INTO @d
END
Close  cur 
DEALLOCATE cur
SELECT * FROM tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this query.

```
UPDATE A SET A.ID = 5000 + B.RowNUM 
FROM TempTable AS A 
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by ID) AS RowNUM FROM TEMPTABLE) AS B 
ON A.ID = B.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

execute this, will get your desired result.

```
SET @i = 5000;
UPDATE table_name SET ID=(@i:=@i+1);
```